# Laravel route in view and send autocomplete parameter to another page

Tags: laravel, autocomplete, routes

I have two webpages A and B, A has a link button like this

```
<a href="{{ route('to_B') }}" class="btn btn-default">Link</a>
```

and B is a page about article lists, and has a table with column [#, books_name, author......]

And also, B has a query table to query data, user can input books_name or author_name, then it'll show the data user wants.

My question is, how to modify link in A Page and let it send autocomplete parameter to B?

The result of B's url may be like this

```
https://{B's path}/?q_author_name={the parameter from Page A}
```

Hope someone can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the query parameter as second argument to `route()`

```
{{ route('to_B', ['q_author_name' => 'Author']) }}
```

would generate

```
https://{B's path}?q_author_name=Author
```

provided you don't have any route parameters in your route definition like

```
Route::get("{B's path}/{param1}", function () {})->name('to_B');
```

in that case the first key from the route array would be passed to the `param1` making your route as

```
https://{B's path}/Author
```